# Why can't I join this tuple in Python?

Tags: python, tuples

```
e = ('ham', 5, 1, 'bird')
logfile.write(','.join(e))
```

I have to join it so that I can write it into a text file.

Comment: BTW, did you know you can write your first line without the parentheses? It's nice to do away with what is essentially noise.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

`join` only takes lists of strings, so convert them first

```
>>> e = ('ham', 5, 1, 'bird')
>>> ','.join(map(str,e))
'ham,5,1,bird'
```

Or maybe more pythonic

```
>>> ','.join(str(i) for i in e)
'ham,5,1,bird'
```

Comment: using str() instead of repr() can cause LOSS OF INFORMATION.

Comment: It depends on what your purpose is, but `str()` is generally what you want to show something to the user (ie in a logfile which was what the OP wanted).

Comment: Indeed. str (__str__ or better, __unicode__) is for humans. And the question states a logfile, which is for humans. So in this case I think str() is better than __repr__.

Comment: Users don't read log files; if inadequately supervised, they ignore them until they run out of disk space then they delete them. Programmers have to read logfiles when investigating problems. Having blurred evidence is at best a major annoyance.

Comment: logfile is just the object name.  (out of conveinence).  Actually, I do want humans to read them :)

Answer (score 12):

`join()` only works with strings, not with integers. Use `','.join(str(i) for i in e)`.

Comment: The comment about tuples without parentheses is great.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) module. It will save a follow-up question about how to handle items containing a comma, followed by another about handling items containing the character that you used to quote/escape the commas.

```
import csv
e = ('ham', 5, 1, 'bird')
with open('out.csv', 'wb') as f:
    csv.writer(f).writerow(e)
```

Check it:

```
print open('out.csv').read()
```

Output:

```
ham,5,1,bird
```

Comment: Seems unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: @LS: All is not what it seems. Simplistically using comma separators without concern for escaping the commas etc comes unstuck very fast.

Answer (score 3):

You might be better off simply converting the tuple to a list first:

`e = ('ham', 5, 1, 'bird')
liste = list(e)
','.join(liste)`